# Return with no expression

Tags: c, return

How does `return` work exactly?

I found the below code and am confused how it works.

You can see in the `if (n==1)` statement the `return` has no value next to it.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) {
   // Base case 
    if (n == 1) 
        return; 
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) 
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) 
            swap(arr[i], arr[i+1]); 
   return  bubbleSort(arr,n-1);
}
```

How does the `return` keyword work in instances such as this?

Comment: It's for `void` functions (like this one) that don't return a value.

Comment: 1. Sort out the formatting. 2. Use braces to avoid confusion.  3. What does swap do? Got a feeling it is not working the way you are expecting

Comment: The problem in this code is `return  bubbleSort(arr,n-1);` . that `return` shouldn't be there; rather just the function call. And you said "ı know that we can return anything(nearly) with "return"" - you can return something of the same type as that declared as the return-type of the function itself; nothing more. In the case of `void` that means *nothing*, so `return;` is viable, the last line is *not*.

Comment: Might be less confusing to replace the function body with this: `if (n > 1) 
    { 
      for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) 
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) 
          swap(arr[i], arr[i+1]); 
          
      bubbleSort(arr,n-1);
    }`.

Comment: I likewise concur with Ed. Your swap appears broken, as you're passing the values to swap by-value. Being C, that will ultimately accomplish nothing. Fixing that and doing what Lundin says looks [like this](https://pastebin.com/n9Paz49j).

Comment: @WhozCraig It might be an ugly macro. `#define swap(a,b) { int tmp = a; a=b; b=tmp; }`

Comment: @Lundin could be.I wouldn't put anything past academia these days.

Comment: @EdHeal I could possibly use braces for the for loop, but other than that I think it's fine

Comment: Use braces.  Avoids confusion. Also avoids errors. Having braces is a good habit. Saves getting caught with your trousers down

Comment: @EdHeal I don't agree. Just make sure you use proper indentation and it's no problem.

Comment: Problem is indentation can get lost over time. Also people may think that indentation is ok. Then code change is made. Problems do occur when just relying on indentation

Comment: Then use an editor that fixes the indentation automatically. I can agree that there are some pros and cons with braces, but there is absolutely no reason to not use proper indentation.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes that is my bad, actually there is no such a thing like "return bubble(...);" but my question is the "return ;" part which is just under the if statement

Comment: How can an editor fix indentation when it disappears.  Eg converting tabs for spaces.

Comment: Also it is up to other peoples choice of ide. That happens in the future

Comment: @EdHeal All good editors have a "Select all, autoindent selection" feature.

Comment: Does that always work as expected? May sometimes give the expected code has a longer for loop

Comment: @EdHeal I have not have enough problems to motivate a "always use braces"-rule

Comment: Good luck. People may bung in an extra line of code assuming indentation is sufficient. Then things stop working as expected. Btw what coding standards do you use. ESA has defined that braces should always be used

Comment: @EdHeal I did not understand what do you mean by "what coding standards do you use".

Comment: If you are allowing anyone that doesn't even know that C does not have indentation dependent syntax modify your C code, then it will end in a catastrophe anyway. In that case, better fail fast. I usually go by the coding style they are using for the Linux kernel. If you have a coding style your company has decided, then you should of course obey it. But I don't think it's a very good style.

Comment: @oguzhanarslan Here is an example: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html

Comment: http://www.esa.int/TEC/Software_engineering_and_standardisation/TECRFBUXBQE_0.html is a good starting point

Comment: @EdHeal And I don't like the ESA standard at all. A simple if else if else that would require 6 (or possibly even 3) lines would require 12 lines. At least allow the opening brace to be on the same line. To much air just makes it hard to see the big picture.

Comment: The idea is to remove the possibility of errors. Everyone makes them. Six sigma - please Google that

Comment: @EdHeal I totally agree with you but as ı said in the beginning  , that is not mine own code ,ı have just found it on the internet.Moreover, some compilers lets the programmer write single statements without any curly brackets but in my opinion it is better to avoid such a usage

Comment: @EdHeal A big monitor does not solve the issue. It helps a little bit, but too much air in the code (or any text) makes it harder to read. Too little also makes it hard to read. And enforcing the us of braces does indeed eliminate a specific error, but I'm not convinced that it necessarily reduces the total number of errors. If it is so undoubtedly better, how comes they are not using it for the Linux kernel?

Comment: @oguzhanarslan ALL C compilers allows you to write single statements without braces.

Comment: Please tell me how the statement "eliminates a specific error" equates to not reducing total number of errors. Surely removing an error will reduce total number of errors

Comment: @EdHeal You are assuming that the extra braces does not cause a higher frequency of another error. This is quite possible, but a lot harder to prove.  And please tag me when you answer so I get notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly this function is recursive and if its `void` it can't return value so it's just flag to stop function

Answer (score 1):

`return` means to stop execution of the current function and return to the caller.

If the function is defined as to return something, then the return statement must have an expression denoting the thing to return.

Your function is correct, except the last `return` statement. Instead of

```
return  bubbleSort(arr,n-1);
```

just write

```
bubbleSort(arr,n-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In traditional C, functions with return type `void` could only use an empty `return` statement to simply exit the function "early".

Functions that have valued return types must return a value in the `return` statement. When you have a value return, you can call a function in the `return` statement that itself returns that value.

In traditional C this makes no sense - you should simply call a void function, not try to return it.

However, in C++ with templates it was discovered that it was incredibly convenient to be able to chain return void-returning functions, and it makes some crazy sort of sense.

So now, you see lines like the second return statement which I think is your actual confusion: `return  bubbleSort(arr,n-1);` This doesn't actually return anything, it just exits the function!

Comment: "Traditional C"? It seems like you just mean C?

Comment: @klutt he may mean older versions like c99 etc.

Comment: @oguzhanarslan And how does it differ from modern C when it comes to this?

Comment: @klutt I'm not a  expert  on C language but as far as ı know , the compilers and also the libraries are optimised and also developed in time .Additionally, with the other languages' development new concepts may have come up so that the developers of C language  make some changes to accept these new concepts

Comment: @oguzhanarslan It may be so, and that's precisely what I'm asking Gem Taylor about.

Comment: I'm going back to K&R and before C99, though to be fair in K&R everything was assumed to be an integer, so probably not that far! Certainly, I have, in the past, been confronted with older compilers that would not accept that second return statement, because "a function returning void does not return a value".